# Добавление элемента в коллекцию

Tags: c#, коллекции

Доброго времени суток!
Обнаружил, что при добавлении элемента в коллекцию List этот элемент не добавляется напрямую, а клонируется. Как этого избежать?

Например, такой код.

```
public Variable TemperatureCouldBlowing {get; set;} 
public List<Variable> Vars = new List<Variable>();
Vars.Add(TemperatureCouldBlowing);
```

Элемент, попавший в коллекцию, будет являться клоном переменной TemperatureCouldBlowing. То есть при изменении переменной элемент коллекции не изменится. Как добавить элемент в коллекцию без клонирования?

[image: Клон]

Comment: `Variable` у вас ссылочный или значимый тип?

Comment: @Shad, не слышал про такие термины. Почитал, но всё же не могу сказать. Этот тип наследуется от DependencyObject, IEquatable, IFormatible. Также содержит поля string Key, double Value, double Min, double Max, bool Display и соответствующие им DependencyProperty.

Comment: "То есть при изменении переменной элемент коллекции не изменится." -- при изменении переменной или изменении поля этой переменной? Это две большие разницы.

Comment: Если объект наследуется от `DependencyObject`, то он должен в `List<>` попадать как ссылка, а не как копия. Вы что-то путаете. Сможете привести **минимальный** пример, воспроизводящий проблему?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы утверждаете, что не слышали о ссылочных и значимых типах, а именно в этом все дело и есть. Не хотелось бы здесь писать объемный рассказ о ссылочных и значимых типах в C#, об этом можете прочесть хотя бы [эту статью](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/4d43ts61(v=vs.90).aspx). Скажу лишь, что типы-значения копируются по значению (ну да, ваш Кэп), а ссылочные типы - по ссылке (Кэп по-прежнему не дремлет). К типам-значениям относятся, например **int,  float, double** ([и прочие подобные из FCL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/s1ax56ch(v=vs.90).aspx)), а также структуры и перечисления. К ссылочным - классы, делегаты, интерфейсы, строки (хотя со строками не все так просто). 
Так вот, небольшой пример, иллюстрирующий разницу хранения ссылочных и значимых типов в контейнере типа **List<T>**:

```
    // ссылочный тип, поскольку является классом
    class Foo
    {
        public int Some { get; set; }
    }

    // =====================

    var lstInt = new List<int>(); // список типов-значений (int)        
    var lstFoo = new List<Foo>(); // список ссылочных типов (Foo)

    int i = 10;
    var foo = new Foo { Some = 11 };
    lstInt.Add(i);   // добавляем int в первый список
    lstFoo.Add(foo);  // добавляем foo во второй

    // выводим текущее значение i
    Console.WriteLine("old i = {0}", i);

    // меняем занесенный в первый список int 
    lstInt[0] = 12;

    // видим, что значение i не изменилось, 
    // поскольку в списке лежит копия i, а не само i
    Console.WriteLine("new i = {0}", i);

    // теперь то же  самое проделаем со вторым списком и переменной foo 
    Console.WriteLine("old foo = {0}", foo.Some);

    // присвоим новое значение свойству класса в списке
    lstFoo[0].Some = 12;

    // видим, что значение foo.Some поменялось, 
    // поскольку в списке лежит ссылка на foo,
    // благодаря через элементы списка мы имеем доступ к членам foo  
    Console.WriteLine("new foo = {0}", foo.Some);

    // можем убедиться, что и при изменении членов foo 
    // аналогично меняются члены элемента списка
    Console.WriteLine("old lstFoo = {0}", lstFoo[0].Some);
    foo.Some = 20;
    Console.WriteLine("new lstFoo = {0}", lstFoo[0].Some);

    Console.WriteLine("old foo = {0}", foo.Some);        
    // теперь заменим саму  ссылку на первый элемент
    // присвоив ее другому элементу
    lstFoo[0] = new Foo { Some = 1 };
    // и снова поменяем Some 
    lstFoo[0].Some = 30;
    // теперь можно видеть, что foo.Some не изменился, поскольку 
    // lstFoo[0] уже указывает не на foo  
    Console.WriteLine("new foo = {0}", foo.Some);
```

Из вышесказанного вытекает нижеследующее - если хотите, чтобы при добавлении в список элементы не "клонировались", а именно добавлялись, то добавляйте туда ссылочные типы, а не типы-значения.